# Pass Variable on Flutter Route

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a code in which I make a certain account, but the result I need to use on another page of the code (Another screen through the route). I was watching and I believe that passing this variable as a parameter is the best way, but I tried everything, but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

**This ListView is what I use for navigation.**

```
ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.airplay),
          title: Text("Rice"),
          subtitle: Text("Cálculo de Rice"),
          selected: false,
          enabled: true,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Rice()));
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.airplay),
          title: Text("Vazios"),
          subtitle: Text("Cálculo de Vazios"),
          selected: false,
          enabled: true,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Vazios()));
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.airplay),
          title: Text("Bgs"),
          subtitle: Text("Calculo de BGS"),
          selected: false,
          enabled: true,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Bgs()));
          },
        )
      ],
    );
```

**This is the account I make and need the *Cont* variable**

```
setState(() {
      double tara = double.parse(taraController.text);
      double amostra = double.parse(pesoAmostraController.text);
      double amostraAgua = double.parse(pesoAmostraAguaController.text);

      double cont = ((amostra + tara) / amostraAgua);

      if (cont > 0) {
        result = "Rice (peso): ${cont.toStringAsPrecision(3)}";
      } else {
        result = "Valor inválido";
      }
    });
  }
```

**Code on GitHub. The file I want to pass the variable is called rice.dart.**
https://github.com/IagoGoncalves/isis.git

Comment: Try to access your variable in rice.dart with `widget.cont`

Comment: @Manuel I think it was not very well explained. I need to use the ** cont ** variable on another screen of the code that is by route path.